# Page load requires a trailing "/"

Tags: customization, pages

I have a new problem today which I didn't have yesterday. Nothing in my code had changed, which is the most confusing part. (Which means the error maybe started before some kind of cacheing?)

None of my custom pages will load without a trailing "/" in the URL. I've never seen this error before and it seems impossible to google for the answer.

Any help?

Comment: Has your host altered server configuration?

Comment: Does your permalink structure under Settings > Permalinks have a trailing slash?

Comment: @s_ha_dum it's on my local machine with MAMP.

Comment: @Milo it's set to the default Post Name setting: http://portigal.dev/sample-post/

Comment: The old theme automatically reroutes pages without the trailing "/" to pages with them. As in from /blog to /blog/. Is this something i need to add to the functions file? Maybe an htaccess file somewhere?

Comment: That's default behavior regardless of theme. I believe it's the [`redirect_canonical`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical) function that enforces presence or absence of trailing slash, depending on whether your permalink structure setting does or does not have the trailing slash.

Comment: This might a be a shot-in-the-dark sort of solution but you could try to install a fresh copy of Wordpress and drop in your theme files and plugins into the new installation and see if the error goes away.  If the error goes away, you at least will know that the problem was outside of your theme.  If the problem persists, you will know that the theme is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a .htaccess issue

use a standard theme - still got the error?
yes --> investigate your .htaccess file in the root of your site
is the rewrite module loaded --> check with phpinfo() on your local server
no --> investigate a .htaccess file within the template directory

in both cases:
check the rewrite rules within the .htaccess file